# Cannot login using Google authentication

Tags: support, login, google-chrome, authentication, google-openid

For some reason, I'm not able to login to an of the SE sites using Google authentication today. Did something change?

[image]

PS. I had to create a direct login on SE using my other e-mail id to report this issue.

Comment: As this server error is generated by Google, we at Stack Exchange likely can't assist with it here, and you should contact Google's support.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog SE team probably needs to follow-up if this is happening to a lot of users and temporarily disable the Google login option until the issue is resolved?

Comment: I had the same issue on SEDE. After a retry it worked. I assumed a local glitch on my end.

Comment: Now it went away @rene

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be temporary problem with Google auth as login from both desktop and mobile browsers did not work. Now I'm able to login from both.